# Show Tree Proof is Incorrect

Tags: graph-theory, trees, fake-proofs

[image]

> It seems the part that says every vertex in H has degree at least two is not necessarily true. The paths could converge prior to seeing vertex v, thus resulting in at least one vertex having degree 1. Therefore the minimum degree is not necessarily 2, meaning it is still possible for H to have at least 2 leaves, therefore this proof is incorrect. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: I agree with you.  Think about a lollipop.  It has one vertex of degree 1, and is also the union of two distinct paths.  Unless the writer is considering two paths where there are no common vertices.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning. We could have $v_1=u_1$, and then $u$ has degree 1 in $H$.

Comment: The proof is indeed incorrect, but it is easily solved by taking the pair of vertices (u,v) minimizing the length $|E(P)|+|E(Q)|$. Then you can argue that the two paths must be edge-disjoint, and even more, they must be internally vertex-disjoint. Hence $P\cup Q$ is a cycle.